# Do not reload entire template

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

I'm working with the Meteor Wordplay example right now.  The project I have going is at https://github.com/ajcrites/meteor-wordplay

One feature that I wanted to add was not showing duplicate words and highlighting the duplicated word in red (animating it).  I got this working via

```
Meteor.call('score_word', word_id, function (error, result) {
    if (result !== undefined) {
        var bg = $("#word_" + result.id).css('background-color');
        $("#word_" + result.id).css('background-color', 'red');
        //Otherwise transition takes effect *before* BG color is applied
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#word_" + result.id).css('transition', 'all 2s')
                .css('background-color', bg);
        }, 10);
    }
});
```

The server will send back a duplicated word ID if there is one.

This works fine, but the problem is that any time a word is added it seems like the entire `> words` template gets redrawn.  I thought it was because the HTML was changing because of the animation that's going on, but I also tried doing this using CSS to do the animation instead, and even without duplicating words I can see in the console that the entire template gets redrawn.

I found a question on Meteor earlier that said the answer is to use a *Meteor Collection* to return from the template instead of some other abstract collection, but as far as I can tell I am:

```
Template.words.words = function () {
    return Words.find({game_id: game() && game()._id,
        player_id: this._id});
};
```

1. How can I stop the entire `> words` template from being redrawn each time?  Is there a way to only add new words to the template?
2. Regardless of the answer to #1, is there a way that I can animate the red BG on a duplicated word and have it go through the full animation even if the `> words` template is updated?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer that hard question, please don't downvote me if I'm mistaken:

1. I think you can't nowadays. Maybe on the next render system they are building.
2. Yes, but I think it's not trivial with the current system. I have a game that I need to rotate a card when users choose one. What I've done was duplicating the div. One receives the last card and the other one receives the current card. So with jQuery I .show() or .hide() them and .addClass() that does the animation. In the class I have transitions and other things that rotate the card.

.

```
{{#with player_next_card}}
<div id="player-next-card" class="inner-card" style="display: none;">
<!--- stuff here --->
</div>
{{/with}}
{{#with player_last_card}}
<div id="player-last-card" class="inner-card">
<!--- same stuff with other info here --->
</div>
{{/with}}
```

Comment: It's very hard to explain, there is a video that shows what I'm trying to say: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=UMFSQCP-n6Y#t=386s